# How to use named instances of HttpService configured via HttpModule.registerAsync?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

In Nest.js, you can get configured HttpServices by dynamically registering the HttpModule, like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule.registerAsync({useClass: FirstAPIHttpOptions })],
  providers: [GlueLogicService]
})
```

Given such setup, GlueLogicService can declare `constructor(private httpService: HttpService)` and get the configured HttpService. But what if I want to have a couple of pre-configured HttpServices? How could I declare and inject two separate HttpServices with different configurations?

While I could declare them both like this, how would the service ask for them both to be injected under different variables?

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.registerAsync({useClass: FirstAPIHttpOptions }),
    HttpModule.registerAsync({useClass: SecondAPIHttpOptions })
  ],
  providers: [GlueLogicService]
})
```